# Error checking on open_lockfile?

Tags: c

I've got a [c program](https://github.com/technion/lol_dht22/blob/master/dht22.c) I"m using off github that intermittently crashes every few days and I think it might be down to "open_lockfile" - maybe the file cannot be opened etc.

How would I go about adding some error level checking on this open_lockfile statement?

```
#define LOCKFILE "/var/run/dht.lock"
int lockfd;
lockfd = open_lockfile(LOCKFILE);
.
.
.
close_lockfile(lockfd);
```

Update: No wonder I couldn't any info in open_lockfile. It's a function within the c code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the code a bit more the open_filelock is a function within the c code.